# Place cited references into the footline of slide

Tags: beamer, bibliographies, citing, footnotes

I am using the following code for the references. How can i place cited references into the footline in each slide?

```
\documentclass[mathserif]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>{
\usetheme{default}
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}[text]}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame} 

\section{References} 
\frametitle{References}

\begin{thebibliography}{99} 
\bibitem{abc} ABC
\bibitem{def} DEF   
\end{thebibliography}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You could do something like `\begin{frame}
blabla\footnote{\cite{abc}}
\end{frame}`, but if you would consider to move to `biblatex`, then you could simply do `\footcite{abc}`

Comment: When I did this i only get [1] the number of the reference at the footline.

Comment: Never place a `\section` inside a frame, always outside.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you want to stay with your manual bibliography, you could do something like

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>{
\usetheme{default}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}

\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}[text]}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame} blabla\footnote{\cite{abc}} \end{frame}

\section{References}
\begin{frame}  
\frametitle{References}

\begin{thebibliography}{99} 
\bibitem[Smith 2013]{abc} ABC
\bibitem{def} DEF   
\end{thebibliography}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

However I would suggest to switch to some automatic bibliography tool like `biblatex`. This will make your life much easier in the long run. It has dedicated commands like `\footcite` which do exactly what I think you want.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[style=authortitle,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
Here is text\footcite{westfahl:space}.
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
Here is text\footfullcite{westfahl:space}.
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\printbibliography
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Using it for the first time is a bit of works, as you have to make a `.bib` file with your references in the format of

```
@incollection{westfahl:space,
  author       = {Westfahl, Gary},
  title        = {The True Frontier},
  subtitle     = {Confronting and Avoiding the Realities of Space in {American}
                  Science Fiction Films},
  pages        = {55-65},
  crossref     = {westfahl:frontier},
  langid       = {english},
  langidopts   = {variant=american},
  indextitle   = {True Frontier, The},
  annotation   = {A cross-referenced article from a \texttt{collection}. This is
                  an \texttt{incollection} entry with a \texttt{crossref}
                  field. Note the \texttt{subtitle} and \texttt{indextitle}
                  fields},
}
```

but after this initial work, it does (nearly) everything for you.

Comment: Any idea how to address this error: "ERROR: LaTeX Error: File `biblatex.sty' not found."?

Comment: Can you add a reference without using any text? That is using something like `\footcite` but with the citation number appear only in the footnote.

Comment: @adosar If you have a new question, please use the "Ask Question" button on the top right.